# The tag [rowwise] is not row wise

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

[rowwise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rowwise) is a [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) function from package [dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dplyr). Its use is generally discouraged and it's not so often used as there are usually more efficient equivalents.

The tag [rowwise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rowwise) has 30 questions since its creation in July 2016, mostly R questions, and the occasional [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) question. Should it be removed?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rowwise

1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

   It is ambiguous, could be general rowwise operations, but is used mostly for this [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) function that doesn't deserve a tag of its own, some pythons questions use it too, and it has no description
2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the Site?

   As said above the function is already losing relevance, but not completely off topic.
3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the Post?

   Searching for `[dplyr] rowwise` will be well enough, no need for [rowwise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rowwise)
4. Does it mean the same thing in all common Contexts?

   See 1.

Comment: [What is the process for tag removal (burnination)?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination)

Comment: I've updated my post, thanks

Comment: Because a function is being discouraged and losing relevance doesn't seem like a good enough reason to burn this tag. If this tag is indeed for that r-function why not give it a proper tag info and remove it from the non-related questions?

Comment: Much more widespread functions don't have their own tags, imo it has not enough added value to deserve it. If your opinion is the consensus I'll gladly do what you suggest.

Comment: Note that this tag has less than 50 questions, so it can qualify for the quick burnination as outlined in the post linked by BDL. You'd need to confer with 2 trusted (>20K rep) users with knowledge on the tag, I think the R chat room would be the place to find such users.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Note that _"A tag must fail all of these tests in order to be considered for burnination."_ and if the tag is about some r-function I would say that is on-topic for SO.

Comment: @AndréKool so, we need a tag for programming, because it's on topic for SO.

Comment: @Braiam I didn't make the rules, I only pointed them out. Also [what kind of programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/functional-programming+or+network-programming+or+programming-languages+or+metaprogramming+or+dynamic-programming+or+reactive-programming+or+template-meta-programming+or+linear-programming+or+generic-programming+or+gpu-programming+or+constraint-programming+or+prototype-programming+or+systems-programming+or+genetic-programming+or+idl-programming-language+or+concurrency+or+procedural-programming+or+logic-programming+or+integer-programming+or+defensive-programming)?

Comment: I educated myself more on the subject. Probably the tag will stay. I assumed the community cared about having a limited amount of relevant tags but from what I gather the idea is just that duplicate tags should be avoided and naming should be careful to avoid mixing different subjects. In this case the tag is indeed a bit messy, but could be cleaned, better defined and let alone. New tags have to be accepted,  but after this step, consensus seems to be "don't bother". Tag `programming` wouldn't be accepted at 1st step, some tags are blacklisted too, maybe `programming` is one of them.

Comment: @AndréKool what rule is there that allows any tag related to SO topic (and if there is that rule, why wasn't abolished for not making sense)? Also [tag:windows] is on topic too?

Comment: We used to use the terms "row major" and "column major" when navigating a 2d-array